# Trigonometry-The distance between L and B when L has walked a distance d must be less than kd, where k is some constant. Find k.

Tags: trigonometry

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wlZp1.png)

have look a at diagram above

=> $O$ is the starting point
=> $0<\alpha<\beta<\pi/2$ 
=> $OL=OB=d$

i worked the distance $LB$ to be $2d\sin((\beta-\alpha)/2)$
but, i am struggling to understand this 'The distance between $L$ and $B$ when $L$ has walked a distance $d$ must be less than $kd$, where $k$ is some constant. Find $k$.

How do i find $k$ ?

Comment: If I am understanding the problem correctly, you are trying to find the maximum distance between L and B?

Comment: Yes, and for what value of 'k' will the distance LB will always be less than kd. d being the distance walked by L and B

Answer (score 0):

Why not $k\ge2\sin\left(\frac{\beta-\alpha}{2}\right)$? Or if you want something independent of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ use $\sin(\cdot) \le 1$ and take $k\ge 2$